# CSS Overlapping Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

For some reason the tabs on this page are overlapping my tooltips. I have tried everything from changing position:absolute to relative and setting different z-indexes without any success.

Everything on this page is using pure CSS. Removing the code from the tabs.css file fixes the problem but of course then my tabs will not work. My webpage: http://www.icb.org.au/DSS

HTML

```
<div class="newslettersec fourcolgal tab tab-anim-slide-down">  

<input type="radio" name="tab" checked id="tab1" class="tab-content-1" value="1">
<label for="tab1"><span><span>Webinars</span></span></a></label>


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2" class="tab-content-2" value="2">
<label for="tab2"><span><span>Queensland</span></span></label>


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3" class="tab-content-3" value="3">
<label for="tab3"><span><span>NSW</span></span></label> 

<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab4" class="tab-content-4" value="4">
<label for="tab4"><span><span>ACT</span></span></a></label>


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab5" class="tab-content-5" value="5">
<label for="tab5"><span><span>Victoria</span></span></label>


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab6" class="tab-content-6" value="6">
<label for="tab6"><span><span>Western Australia</span></span></label>   


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab7" class="tab-content-7" value="7">
<label for="tab7"><span><span>South Australia</span></span></label> 


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab8" class="tab-content-8" value="8">
<label for="tab8"><span><span>Tasmania</span></span></label>


<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab9" class="tab-content-9" value="9">
<label for="tab9"><span><span>NT</span></span></label>

    <ul class="ourHolder">
        <div class="tab-content-1">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="tooltip">
                    <p class="networksheadingthumb">
                        Sydney - Balmain
                    </p>
                    <p class="networksthumb">
                        21st October, 2013<br />
                        Starting 6:15pm
                    </p>
                    <p class="networksthumb">
                        Facilitated by:<br />
                        Sue Taylor
                    </p>
                <span>
                      <img class="facilitatorimage" src="/ICB/images/Shane Taylor HORSHAM.jpg" width="100" height="155" style="float:right; margin-top:10px;" />
                      <h6 class="facilitatorname">Sue Taylor</h6>
                      <p class="facilitatorbio">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                      </p>
                      <p class="facilitatorbio">
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                      </p>
                      <p class="facilitatorbio">
                        An unrelated company with the same name was incorpor in California in 1991. As of 2012, its operations are suspended run regular network meetings around the country please log using link here.
                      </p>
                </span>
            </div>      
        </li>   

        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-2">
            @content[NetworkEventQld]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-3">
            @content[NetworkEventNSW]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-4">
            @content[NetworkEventACT]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-5">
            @content[NetworkEventVIC]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-6">
            @content[NetworkEventWA]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-7">
            @content[NetworkEventSA]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-8">
            @content[NetworkEventTAS]
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-9">
            @content[NetworkEventNT]
        </div>                  
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

tabs.css

```
.tab {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
}
.tab {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #666;
}
.tab > input {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.tab > label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab > label.inverse {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
.tab > label.disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
.tab > label span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.tab > label span span {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #848484;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:1px;
    transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s;
    -o-transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s, color 0.4s;    
}
.tab > label:hover span span {
    background: #438bcf;
    color: #fff;    
}
.tab > label.disabled span span {
    background: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}
.tab > input:checked + label {
    cursor: default;
}
.tab > input:checked + label span span {
    background: #438bcf;
    color: #fff;
}
.tab > ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.tab > ul > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.8s, -o-transform 0.8s; 
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.8s, -ms-transform 0.8s;   
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.8s, -moz-transform 0.8s; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
}
.tab > .tab-content-1:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-1,
.tab > .tab-content-2:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-2,
.tab > .tab-content-3:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-3,
.tab > .tab-content-4:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-4,
.tab > .tab-content-5:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-5,
.tab > .tab-content-6:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-6,
.tab > .tab-content-7:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-7,
.tab > .tab-content-8:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-8,
.tab > .tab-content-9:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-9,
.tab > .tab-content-10:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-10,
.tab > .tab-content-11:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-11,
.tab > .tab-content-12:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-12,
.tab > .tab-content-13:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-13,
.tab > .tab-content-14:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-14,
.tab > .tab-content-15:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-15,
.tab > .tab-content-16:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-16,
.tab > .tab-content-17:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-17,
.tab > .tab-content-18:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-18,
.tab > .tab-content-19:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-19,
.tab > .tab-content-20:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-20{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
/**/
/* animations */
/**/
.tab-anim-slide-down > ul > div {
    -o-transform: translateY(15%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(15%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(15%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(15%);
}
.tab > .tab-content-1:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-1,
.tab > .tab-content-2:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-2,
.tab > .tab-content-3:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-3,
.tab > .tab-content-4:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-4,
.tab > .tab-content-5:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-5,
.tab > .tab-content-6:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-6,
.tab > .tab-content-7:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-7,
.tab > .tab-content-8:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-8,
.tab > .tab-content-9:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-9,
.tab > .tab-content-10:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-10,
.tab > .tab-content-11:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-11,
.tab > .tab-content-12:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-12,
.tab > .tab-content-13:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-13,
.tab > .tab-content-14:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-14,
.tab > .tab-content-15:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-15,
.tab > .tab-content-16:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-16,
.tab > .tab-content-17:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-17,
.tab > .tab-content-18:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-18,
.tab > .tab-content-19:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-19,
.tab > .tab-content-20:checked ~ ul > .tab-content-20{
    -o-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
}

.panes {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

}
.panes div {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.panes h4 {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#000;
}
.panes p {
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
.panes img {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

tooltip.css

```
    div.tooltip {outline:none;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:dotted 1px blue;}
    div.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
    div.tooltip > span 
    {
        width:200px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-left: -4px;
        margin-top:-450px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 10;       
        position: absolute;

        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;  

        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -o-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;


        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;      
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;       

        -webkit-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-top;
        -webkit-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;  
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

        -moz-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-top;
        -moz-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;  
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

        -o-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-top;
        -o-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;  
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

        transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-top;
        transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;  
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
    }

    /*div.tooltip > span:hover,*/
    div.tooltip:hover > span
    {
        opacity: 1;
        text-decoration:none;
        visibility: visible;
        overflow: visible;
        margin-top:-490px;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: -4px;      
    }

    div.tooltip span b {

        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: -19px;

        display: block;
        position: absolute;

        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);

        -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
        -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;

        display: none\0/;
        *display: none;
    }

div.tooltip > span {
    color: #000000; 

    background: #FBF5E6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBF5E6 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FBF5E6), color-stop(100%,#FFFFFF));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FBF5E6', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0 );

    border: 1px solid #CFB57C;       
}    

div.tooltip span b {
    background: #FBF5E6;
    border-top: 1px solid #CFB57C;
    border-right: 1px solid #CFB57C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your page, I find that the issue seems to be that the height of the ul element is limiting the tooltip. I would suggest not to use a ul element and make a box that encloses all of it and fit the boxes in a similar to how it is set up right now. also your navigation on top (the label size) is quite larger than the visible button. You can also make that it's own div and the content two different divs so they won't overlap and you can style them differently instead of putting it in the same element.